# Override Attribute of Property in Derived Class

Tags: .net, vb.net

How can I override an annotated attribute in my base class, when inheriting in my class?

Example of base class:

```
<Serializable>
<XmlRoot("INTERFACE")>
Public MustInherit Class WM_Interface

    Private m_Message_Type As String
    Private m_Event_DTTM As String
    Private m_Business_Unit As String

    <XmlElement(ElementName:="MESSAGE_TYPE")>
    Public Property Message_Type() As String
        Get
            Return m_Message_Type
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Message_Type = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <XmlElement(ElementName:="EVENT_DTTM")>
    Public Property Event_DTTM() As String
        Get
            Return m_Event_DTTM
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Event_DTTM = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <XmlElement(ElementName:="BUSINESS_UNIT")>
    Public Property Business_Unit() As String
        Get
            Return m_Business_Unit
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Business_Unit = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Now in my derived class, I want to add a property, but I also want to make BUSINESS_UNIT isNullable = False

```
<Serializable>
<XmlRoot("INTERFACE")>
Public Class DERIVED_WM_Interface
    Inherits WM_Interface

    Private m_NEWPROPERTY As String

    <XmlElement(ElementName:="NEWPROPERTY", IsNullable:=False)>
    Public Property NEWPROPERTY() As String
        Get
            Return m_NEWPROPERTY
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_NEWPROPERTY = value
        End Set
    End Property

    'Also want to make isNullable = False for base class property of Business_Unit
    'How?
End Class
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried overriding the property and setting the attribute in the base class?

Answer (score 1):

I think by default it's already set to False. But if you want to change it, you just need to override the property.

```
<Serializable>
<XmlRoot("INTERFACE")>
Class Class1

    <XmlElement(ElementName:="SomeProperty")>
    Public Overridable Property TestProperty As String

End Class

<Serializable>
<XmlRoot("INTERFACE")>
Class Class2
    Inherits Class1

    <XmlElement(ElementName:="SomeProperty", IsNullable:=True)>
    Public Overrides Property TestProperty As String

End Class
```

With a quick test, you can see the result.

```
    For Each pi As PropertyInfo In GetType(Class1).GetProperties()
        Dim att As XmlElementAttribute

        att = CType(pi.GetCustomAttributes(GetType(XmlElementAttribute), True)(0), XmlElementAttribute)

        Console.WriteLine(att.IsNullable) ' Display: False
    Next

    For Each pi As PropertyInfo In GetType(Class2).GetProperties()
        Dim att As XmlElementAttribute

        att = CType(pi.GetCustomAttributes(GetType(XmlElementAttribute), True)(0), XmlElementAttribute)

        Console.WriteLine(att.IsNullable) ' Display: True
    Next
```

Comment: I think that's the key. You have to set the base property to overridable. Thanks!